# Disabled unicode characters in a font?

Tags: fonts, fontforge

I'm editing a `woff` font file using FontForge (version 20190801 on windows 10), and I would like to add a glyph for the unicode character [0xD835](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1d44e/index.htm).

However the box for this character has a cross on the upper box where usually the unicode char is displayed. Moreover its description in the top bar is "surrogate high, non private use" (what does this mean?), see images below

[image]

[image]

I tried copying a glyph from another character and pasting it into the 0xD835 box, obtaining this

[image]

but the character is not displaying when I use it. Moreover, FontForge crashes if I click on "glyph info".

There are many other characters which cannot be used, are these characters permanently disabled or is there a way to use them?

The file I'm working on is `cmunrm.woff` of the *Computer Modern Serif* font, available [here](https://www.checkmyworking.com/cm-web-fonts/). Here is the direct link to the woff [file](https://github.com/fontforge/fontforge/files/3830739/cmunrm.zip).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

But there is no such thing as "the unicode character D835". everything between D800 and DFFF is illegal on its own, and can only be used (but still not assigned) in pairs of a low and high surrogate code in the UTF-16 encoding to resolve a number greater than 16 bits in what is a 16 bit fixed width encoding scheme.

You're probably not even using UTF-16 (since your font is likely using separate UCS-2 and UCS-4 cmap subtables) but to make sure no one does anything funny with those codepoints, the Unicode standard [forbids the use of those codepoints for anything other than surrogate pairs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Character_Set_characters#Surrogates) anyway.

See https://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode12.0.0/ch23.pdf pp890 for the more most authoritative, detailed information as can be found on the internet about surrogate pairs.

Comment: Thank you very much to solve the mistery! The strange thing, about which I was not very precise, is that by writing in my site editor `&#x1d44e;` or directly ``, what gets displayed is the italic "a" of the default site font (i think times new roman) which is not the font that I'm using now. From this I get that my font doesn't contain that character, so the site searches in the default font and actually finds it, and I was trying to understand if it is possible to change the character. But from the sources you linked, it seems that there is no way. Is this the case? Thanks again

Comment: Here a screenshot of the printe character https://i.imgur.com/OezkZpq.png

Comment: I'm confused: of course it works if you type `&#x1d44e` because `1D44E` [is the codepoint for that character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1D44E/index.htm). So why are you trying to put things at `D835`? That number only shows up in the byte sequence for the UTF-16 encoded value (in which 1D44E _has_ to be encoded as the two bytes D835 + DC4E because it's larger than what fits in a 16-bit value). However, fonts don't use any specific encodings internall, and FontForge shows you unicode codepoints, so... put your glyph at codepoint 1D44E, where it should be?

Comment: Thank you for the help, excuse me if I don't explain me very well, I'm very new to this. I tried some days ago to search for the character/codepoint `1D44E` in my font using FontForge, but I could not find it. All the characters in my font have a code with length 4, such as `0021` and `20AC`, and when I have to search for them in FontForge I have to write `0x0021` and `0x20AC`. But `1D44E` has length 5, looking at fileformat.com I see that the UTF-32 (hex) code is `0x0001D44E`, but when searching for that code in my font using FontForge it tells me that it could not find the glyph.....

Comment: .....that's why I tried to edit `0xD835` and `0xDC4E` instead, I thought that by editing them both it would work too.

Comment: I clicked on Encoding > Reencode > ISO 10646-1 (Unicode, Full). Then the list of glyphs became much larger, I searched again for `0x0001D44E`  and this time I found it. I put my glyph at that codepoint and it worked, now it is displayed on my site! Is it safe to reencode in such a way?

Comment: Yes, you need to inform FontForge which unicode blocks you intent to support - once you're done creating your font, you can tell it to "compact". And while this is how you make fonts, do beware that if you're editing someone's font, that's _probably_ a license violation. What you might want to do instead is create a dedicated font with just your character, and then use it on your site by taking advantage of CSS font fallback, adding it to the font chain before the generic category keyword (the ones that are `serif`, `monospace`, etc)

Comment: Thank you so much for big help! I'm doing that right now, I created a new file (ctrl+n), reencoded it to `ISO 10646-1 (Unicode, Full)`, but when I pasted a glyph from the original font to the new one, the heigh is wrong. Look at this to better understand https://i.imgur.com/rJ4uENQ.png It seems that when I copy a glyph, the height of the box containing it is not copied, so when I paste it the height is different. You know how to fix it? I'm sure is not a big deal

Comment: Ah, maybe I have to change the settings in `Element > FontInfo > OS/2`. **EDIT** found it `Element > FontInfo > General`

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help you learn how to use fontforge, because that would take days, but I can recommend not making a new font - instead, take the old font, _clear it_, then put in your desired glyph and update the file info, and generate a new font. Also, remember that glyphs are copyrightable, so if you copied a glyph from a different font, that _may_ in fact be illegal... you'll want to double-check the license for whatever you got the glyph from (and if there is no license, by law that means it's "all rights reserved" and you can't do anything with it).